# Replacing multiple chars using sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a string:

```
xy-uv>ab-cd-ed-ef-gh<
```

I need to be convert it to:

```
xy-uv>ab cd ef gh<
```

Basically, I need to replace the `-` with a space in all characters between the `>` and the `<`.

How can I do this using `sed`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does it work? If not, what is the (wrong) result?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is:

```
sed 'h; s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/; s/-/ /g; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*>\)\(.*\)\(<.*\)/\2\1\4/'
```

In a multiline script it would be:

```
h 
s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/
s/-/ /g 
G 
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*>\)\(.*\)\(<.*\)/\2\1\4/
```

It is a common pattern when you want to make a substitution only for a specific part of a line. It takes advantage of the **hold** space (`h`, `G` commands). Basically you make a copy of the line (from the **pattern** space) to the hold space. Then isolate the part between '>' and '<', and substitute '-' with ' '. Then use the multiline get `G` command to append the hold space to the pattern space. In between there will be a new line character (the `G` command is a **multiline** command). In the last line we simply rearrange the two lines using **groups** and the replacement metacharacters \N (where N is the group number).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed` script :

```
s/>([^>]+)</\n>\1<\n/g
:loop
s/(\n[>][^ ]+)-([a-z ]*[<]\n?)/\1 \2/g
t loop
s/\n//g
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# sed -r -f b.sed 
xy-uv>ab-cd-ed-ef-gh< 
xy-uv>ab cd ed ef gh<
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier with `awk` than `sed` as you can do substitutions on given fields:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$2)}1' FS='>' OFS='>' file
xy-uv>ab cd ed ef gh<
```

Comment: If there were characters with `-` interleaved after a `<`, this `awk` also would remove them.

Comment: If that was the problem being asked it could be fixed by setting multiple characters and `FS` using the operator or a character class and `OFS` would depend on the exacted problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(>[^<]*)-([^<]*<)/\1 \2/;ta' file
```